# Clock cycle of time_t and getting time problem

Tags: c++, time-t

I am trying to get current raw time (the one that is NOT human readable) in my simple while loop. I searched time_t clock cycle period but I couldn't find any information about it.

1st issue: Does anyone know the clock cycle period of time_t in C++?

2nd issue: When I print time ltime, it look same all the time.

```
time_t ltime;
while (count <= 1000) {
  time( & ltime); //I expect this to get current time in every cycle
  cout << "Current time " << ltime << endl;
  count++;
}
```

I already checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/time-time32-time64?view=vs-2019) link but it does not give information about clock period.

Comment: Of course it does: "*Returns the time as **seconds**...*". So the resolution of time_t is 1 second.

Comment: @rustyx now I see and understand, thank you, do you have any idea about 2nd issue

Comment: 2nd issue: probably takes less than 1 second to run.  It's only 1000 iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()`

Edit:

Use `std::system_clock::now()` and `std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t()`

Comment: In actual long code I put it in uint32_t map, so its type is not suitable that is why I chose time_t

Comment: thank you I did `uint32_t time = static_cast<uint32_t>(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count());`

Comment: you should not represent time with 32bit. consider the year 2038 problem.